# How to use If statement and str.contains() to create a new dataframe column

Tags: pandas, string, function, if-statement, contains

I am trying to use if statement and str.contains() to generate a label which I can apply to a new column,
but I am getting Attribute Error .....

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

How Can I incorporate str.contains() in the if statement and create a column?

This is a simple if statement I have tried:

```
def f(row):
    if(row['ContentTitle'] == 'Mr Bean'):
        return 'English Movie'
    if(row['ContentTitle'] == 'Jurassic Park'):
        return 'English'
    if(row['ContentTitle'] == 'Okwonko'):
        return 'Nigeria Movie'
    if(row['ContentTitle'].str.contains('Mama Ntilie')):
        return 'Swahili Movie'
    else:
        return 'Others'
```

I have tried to use str.contain `('Mama Ntilie')` because this is a series and it has multiple seasons and Episode, labeling each one will be tiresome

```
Streamers_Data_Sample['Content_Watched'] = Streamers_Data_Sample.apply(f, axis = 1)
```

Comment: .str.contains() will be used for Series. In your case it is a str, you can directly use following code


if "Mama Nitle" in row['ContentTitle"]:
    return "Swahili Movie"

Comment: This has worked, Let me try the approach on a large dataset, Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Thanks @Manojbiroj, The approach has worked for a large data set of more than 10 Mil rows